# Return entity record value based on custom value in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm making an API and I need to display data from entity based on action type. For example, I have User and his visibility preferences (to hide/show his name for other people). Doing this like that:

```
<?php
// entity

public function getSurname()
{
    $visibility = $this->getVisibility();
    if($visibility['name'] == 0)
        return $this->surname;
    return '';
}
```

is ok, but if User is logged in, I want to show him his name, for example, in edit account.
The best way I think is to edit record when I get it from database, but how to this on doctrine object?

```
<?php
//controller

$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:User')->findOneById($id);
$user = $this->getVisibility();

if($user != $this->getUser() && $visibility['name'] == 0)
    $user->setSurname(''); //but this save this to DB, not to "view"
```

UPDATE

Unfortunately (or I'm doing something wrong) my problem can't be solved by Snake answer, beause when I do this code:

```
<?php
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle')-findOneById($id);

return array(
    self::USER => $user
);
```

In my API response, entity modifications don't work, because I think this is getting record directly from DB? And I need return whole object like in code above.

UPDATE2

I found workaround for this

```
<?php
// entity

/**
 * @ORM\PostLoad
 */
public function postLoad() {
    $this->surname = $this->getSurname();
}
```

and then I can just return full $user object

Comment: What is the problem with my answer? You get the name according to visible or not. What is `return array ( self :: USER => $user);`? Why do you use `self::USER`? Explain it please.

Comment: It's only constant, don't focus on this. const ORGANIZER_RETURN = 'organizer' and then in API I have user object in array('user' => $user)

Comment: And if you use `{{ user.getSurname( app.user ) }}` what does it happen?

Comment: In API (Fosrestbundle) I don't use it, updated part of my question is giving me json response with User object. Twig is not involved in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the surname depends of visibility, you can add the [`Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/EquatableInterface.html) and edit your function:

```
// entity

public function getSurname(Acme\DemoBundle\User $user = null)
{
    // Nothing to compare or is the owner
    if( !is_null( $user ) && $this->isEqualTo($user) ){ 
        return $this->surname;
    }

    // else...
    $visibility = $this->getVisibility();
    if($visibility['name'] == 0)
        return $this->surname;
    return '';
}
```

After in your controller you only must get the surname:

```
//controller

$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:User')->findOneById($id);

// If the user is the owner, show the surname, otherwise it shows the surname depends of visibility
$surname = $user->getSurname( $this->getUser() );
```

Also, you can execute the logic in the controller (check if is the same user and get the visibility...).

I suggest you read about [**ACL**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) too.

Comment: Great, thanks, but one more question. In my current edit account code I have in twig {{ user.surname }} so to work it with your code I have to edit controller like you said or is the simpler way?

Comment: You can call to `getSurname` but you must to pass it the actual User loged. Also you can inject the `security.context` but it is not recommended. I haven't tried but I think you can do `{{ user.getSurname( app.user ) }}`

Comment: Yep, it works :) btw, I changed your first checking line to if( !is_null( $user ) && $this->isEqualTo($user) ) because for not logged users it displays surname in case it was hidden. Thanks for help.

Comment: Oh yep! It is more logic. I change my answer to `!is_null`. I donk't know i thought.

Comment: unfortunately this is not solved.. see question update

Comment: I don't understand you. You mark the answer and now, uncheck (you could change because i edited my answer).

Comment: because I'm still have problem to retrive modified values to API response